# How to skip timer in Windows service while processing some excel file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, service

I have a service that will check and pick the excel file from ftp based on (filename, process status flag and date of that file given in database) and read and process the file continuously. It will generate log files.

If it is still processing when the timer fires again, I should skip the time interval for an additional hour to allow it to complete.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
    timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
    timer1.Interval = 43200000; //execute for every 12 hours
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Library.WriteErrorLog("Timer is called .......................");
    CheckprocessFile();
}

protected override void OnStop() {
    timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the timer code that you have?

Comment: protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
            timer1.Interval = 43200000; //execute for every 12 hours
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Library.WriteErrorLog("Timer is called .......................");
                CheckprocessFile();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

Comment: Update your question with that, and format it as code. Easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried something like this?

```
public static int interval {get;set;}
public bool? done = null;    // set to false when app first loads

protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
    if(done == null){
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Interval = 43200000; //execute for every 12 hours
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }
}

private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Library.WriteErrorLog("Timer is called .......................");
    if((done == null) || (done == true)) 
    {   
        done = false;
        CheckprocessFile();
        done = true;
    }
    else
    {
        done = false;
        interval = 3600000; 
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Interval = interval;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }


}

protected override void OnStop() {
    timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I will try to implement this and update if any concerns.Thank you @ -hypnotized_bythemess

Comment: I don't why my service is getting stopped after 5-6 hours automatically. But Service properties I have given as "automatic" run. Eventhough service is getting stoped. Please suggest some solution @hypnotized_bythemess

Comment: assign the service the property of "automatic restart on failure" through services.msc.